# Роль/применение Spring и Hibernate в Android

Tags: android, spring, hibernate

Где в Андроиде используют эти фрейморки(как правильно?) :

- Spring
- Hibernate

?

Comment: вы задаете очевидно неправильный вопрос. Вы хотите, чтобы кто-то вам привел все возможные применения этих фреймворков?

Comment: @metalurgus, все возможные не надо. Хотя бы один-два самых частых применений.